# querying Recently account viewed

Tags: query

How how do I query recent account views and group by LastViewedDate  [image: This is the error message]

```
SELECT Id, Name  
              FROM Account
               ORDER BY Name DESC limit 10 FOR VIEW
```

I used to have it like this, but my test case is keep failing

```
SELECT SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate 
                       FROM account 
                       WHERE LastModifiedDate !=null ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC limit 10

static testmethod void testOppExt_TestMethod(){


     Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(Name = 'TestOpp', StageName='Test', CloseDate = Date.today());
      insert testOpp;

      Account testAcc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
      insert testAcc;

      Contact con = new Contact(LastName='Test',AccountId=testAcc.id);
      insert con;

      Test.startTest();
      OppExt testCon = new OppExt();
      Contact conn = testCon.contact;
      Account  Accn = testCon.acc;
      Test.stopTest();
    }
```

Error Message

Component Errors
API Name
Type
Line
Column
Error Message
0 0 , Details: Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 0%, at least 75% test coverage is required.
0 0 SiteRegisterControllerTest.null(), Details: line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed: oppext null
0 0 SiteLoginControllerTest.null(), Details: line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed: oppext null
0 0 SiteRegisterController.null(), Details: line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed: oppext null
0 0 testnewOpportunityController.null(), Details: line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed: oppext null
0 0 SiteLoginController.null(), Details: line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed: oppext null
0 0 testOppExt.null(), Details: line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed: oppext null
0 0 OppExt.null(), Details: line 32, column 17: No such column 'LastViewedDate' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. null

Comment: Maybe posting your test class would help??

Comment: Hi @Eric I just did it

Comment: There is nothing is your test that would fail as you have no asserts. What do you mean by "Keeps Failing"

Comment: @Eric I get  so many errors in the production deployment such as SiteLoginController.null(), Details: line -1, column -1: Previous load of class failed: oppext null  ... , Details: Average test coverage across all Apex Classes and Triggers is 0%, at least 75% test coverage is required.  .... when I do this in mavenmate I get 100 percent. The problem is with that query

Comment: In Production - Goto Setup -> Develop -> Apex Classes - then click compile all classes. I bet that it will give you errors and has nothing to do with what you are trying to deploy? When asking a question these types of details are very helpful to include as your question is completely different that the problem in your comment

Comment: @Eric Ill do that now but let you know it just passed with this query SELECT Id, Name  
              FROM Account
               ORDER BY Name DESC limit 10 FOR VIEW

Comment: Good to know. But the errors you get on deployment need to be put in your question as they are relevant. If a simple change of the query resolves it then we need to know what those errors are so the problem can be identified

Comment: @Eric what should I do?I dont want to order it by name, i still want the other one. The LastViewedDate works perfectly fine in Sandbox, it just doesnt let me send it to production

Comment: @Eric ya the second query is not returning me the right information :( This is no good SELECT Id, Name  
              FROM Account
               ORDER BY Name DESC limit 10 FOR VIEW

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29832/discussion-between-bez-and-eric).

Comment: @Eric Ill update my question and post all the errors that I am getting

Comment: Hi @Eric I have attached the error message. that I am getting

Comment: What is the API version of your class (if not v34.0 try changing it)? Executing the query in the dev console works just fine. In your post you have two SELECT (should not be that way). Try and execute the SOQL in the dev console and see if it works. Just in case the code here does not match what you have in your org (if this is the case, shame, shame), you cannot include the LastViewedDate as a column in the query, you can only filter / sort by it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to access LastViewedDate on Account object SQL](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94758/unable-to-access-lastvieweddate-on-account-object-sql)

Comment: @Eric I couldn't change the title and make it more specific here , that is why I opened it.  the Version is  <apiVersion>31.0</apiVersion>

Comment: @Eric I updated to V 34.0 and still same issue

Comment: Possible answer at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115585/how-to-get-recent-view-records