# Unable to access LastViewedDate on Account object SQL

Tags: account, sqlserver

I am trying to get the list of last 10 accounts viewed. The code seems to be working in sandbox and workbench but when I try deploying it in production, I get the error: No such column 'LastViewedDate' on entity 'Account'.

```
SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate 
                           FROM account 
                           WHERE LastModifiedDate !=null ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC limit 10

<apiVersion>31.0</apiVersion>
```

Attached the error messags[image: The error message]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a known issue. See [When performing several SOQL queries from different Apex classes, "No such column 'LastViewedDate' on entity " is thrown](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0tvAAC).

You mention that you are using API version 31.0, which should be sufficient. Are there other apex classes involved in the test that have an earlier API version?

Comment: No Its only one class, but I fixed it this way

Comment: SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate 
                           FROM account 
                           WHERE LastModifiedDate !=null ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC limit 10

Comment: LastModified instead of view...

Comment: Salesforce is fixing this Known Issue with the [Enable Improved Caching of Org Schema](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353660&type=1&mode=1) critical update on or before Aug 12, 2020