# How to get Recent View Records?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

can we get recently viewed records? like standard page recent Items.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use **[`RecentlyViewed`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm)** object.

[**RecentlyViewed**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recentlyviewed.htm)

> Represents records that the current user has recently viewed or
>   referenced (by viewing a related record).

You just need to query this object and specify the type of object

Example

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM RecentlyViewed  WHERE Type ='Account'
```

You can also use ORDER BY `LastViewedDate` field to get latest records

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM RecentlyViewed  WHERE Type ='Account' ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC
```