# Recently Viewed list filter for custom objects

Tags: recentlyviewed

Why salesforce does not show Recently Viewed List filter for Custom objects in Salesforce classic?

Is there anyway we can create list filter for Recently View records. I cannot find LastViewedDate while creating new View.

Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in saying you can't create a list view for this. The recently viewed is not a list view, it's typically the home page for the tab. To get here simply click on the tab name on your tab bar or from the **+** menu (it's the page right before you click the **go** button):

[image]

Also, if you have your side panel open you can usually see a list of recently viewed records there; however, this is not object specific:

[image]

Lastly, if your custom object is searchable, you can see recently accessed records in the global search:

[image]

### Update based on comments

If you have overridden the page, you'll want to get the recent records in your page controller and then add those to a list on your home page to reproduce the functionality.

[Get Recent Records via SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115585/how-to-get-recent-view-records)

> Example
>
> `SELECT Id, Name FROM RecentlyViewed  WHERE Type ='Account'`
>
> You can
>   also use ORDER BY LastViewedDate field to get latest records
>
> `SELECT Id, Name FROM RecentlyViewed  WHERE Type ='Account' ORDER BY
>   LastViewedDate DESC`

I believe that an SObject Describe via the rest API returns a list of recent records as well.

[Rest API Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_basic_info.htm)

Comment: But I need to override custom object home tab. i have to add one more section below the recently viewed section. When i used <apex:enhancedlist> in the VF then i cannot see Recenly viewed section. Please provide suggestion for this.

Comment: @SFDCcoder You should update your question to explain that you have overridden the home page with a visualforce page so that people can provide you with answers that may actually help you.

Comment: @SFDCcoder Updated my answer with more information for you.